# What values can you assign to an unsigned char?

Tags: c

Let's say a function needs to return the bit pattern 00100010.

I want to return this pattern with the 5th bit from the right to be on.

Is this valid?

The function takes in the parameter `settings` which represents 00100010.

```
unsigned char mask = 20; 
return mask | settings;
```

or is it not possible to assign the value `20` to an `unsigned char`?

Comment: An `unsigned char` is an integer with `sizeof` equal to 1 byte. If we assume 1 byte is 8 bits, then you can assign the values 0-255 to it.

Comment: `unsigned char` is guaranteed to have at least 8 bits. so the value is within the range of the type, but it should be written in hex: `unsigned char mask = 0x20;`

Comment: In C and some other languages, you should not read into the word "char" that it is storing text. In others, "char" must be or should be text.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer of rsp a bit confusing. So let me clear this up.

characters like `'a'` are just interpretations of an integer according to a character table. for example this statement is true according to the ascii table `'a' == 97`.

So you are free to write an integer into an `(un)signed char`.
It is essentially the same.

If you use `printf("%c\n",var)` the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written, it doesn't matter if you did `var = 'a'` or `var = 97`

edit: used the description of the standard thx to chux

Comment: [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) would be a better example. ASCII is only used in certain, limited realms.

Comment: "number in var gets reinterpreted as the char" --> The C spec says "... the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written."

Answer (score 1):

> What values can you assign to an `unsigned char`?

The smallest value is 0 as `unsigned char` is some *unsigned integer* type.

The biggest value is provided `<limits.h>`: `UCHAR_MAX`

`UCHAR_MAX` is at least 255 and is some power-of 2 - 1 like 255, 511, 65535, etc.  It is very commonly 255.

If an integer value outside this range is assigned to an `unsigned char`, the value is reduced by adding/subtracting `UCHAR_MAX + 1` until in range.

---

The following code is OK, but unclear if 20 is the needed mask or hexadecimal 0x20.

```
unsigned char mask = 20;  // bits 0001 0100 
// or
unsigned char mask = 0x20;// bits 0010 0000
```

Note that the binary pattern 0010_0010<sub>2</sub> is 34<sub>10</sub> or 22<sub>16</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned char` is guaranteed to have at least 8 bits, so the value representing the binary 100000 is within the range of the type, but it should be written in hex:

```
unsigned char mask = 0x20;
return mask | settings;
```

or simply:

```
return 0x20 | settings;
```

Note that if `settings` as the binary value 00100010 (`0x22`), it already has the 5th bit set.